# Postgresql - Removing duplicate rows per each user and customer

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In postgres, I have two tables: blog and blog_history. blog_history is to keep track of users and which blogs they read.
Tables structures are as follows:

blog table:

```
CREATE TABLE blog (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    title text,
    description text,
    body text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
);
```

blog_history table:

```
CREATE TABLE blog_history (
    customer_username text NOT NULL,
    created_by text NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    post_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT fk_post_id
        FOREIGN KEY(post_id) 
        REFERENCES blog(id)
);
```

I have some duplicate rows in blog_history table that has the same post_id which is unnecessary.
I want to remove all duplicate rows by keeping one distinct for each created_by and each customer_username.
Example:

```
SELECT customer_username, created_by, post_id from blog_history;

 customer_username |    created_by     | post_id 
-------------------+-------------------+---------
 companyA             | bob@example.com |       1
 companyA             | bob@example.com |       3
 companyA             | bob@example.com |       2
 companyA             | bob@example.com |       2
 companyA             | bob@example.com |       2
 companyA             | bob@example.com |       3
 companyB             | bob@example.com |       3
 companyB             | bob@example.com |       3
 companyA             | tam@example.com |       1
 companyA             | tam@example.com |       3
 companyA             | tam@example.com |       3
 companyA             | tam@example.com |       2
```

After deleting duplicates, result should be like this:

```
 customer_username |    created_by     | post_id 
-------------------+-------------------+---------
 companyA             | bob@example.com |       1
 companyA             | bob@example.com |       3
 companyA             | bob@example.com |       2
 companyB             | bob@example.com |       3
 companyA             | tam@example.com |       1
 companyA             | tam@example.com |       3
 companyA             | tam@example.com |       2
```

So, I want to leave only one distinct post_id and **delete** all duplicate ones with the same post_id for same customer_username and same created_by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a column that would identify each row. Add the primary key to the table:

```sql
alter table blog_history
    add id int generated always as identity primary key;
```

Now you can easily identify rows with the lowest `id` in groups of duplicated rows.

```sql
delete from blog_history
where id not in (
    select distinct on (customer_username, created_by, post_id) id
    from blog_history
    order by customer_username, created_by, post_id, id
    );
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/lUUSkB5C)

Answer (score 1):

```
delete 
from t
where ctid in
(
select ctid
from
(select *, ctid, row_number() over(partition by customer_username,created_by,post_id order by post_id) as rn
from   t
) t2
where rn > 1
);

select *
from   t
```

| customer_username | created_by | post_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| companyA | bob@example.com | 1 |
| companyA | bob@example.com | 3 |
| companyA | bob@example.com | 2 |
| companyB | bob@example.com | 3 |
| companyA | tam@example.com | 1 |
| companyA | tam@example.com | 3 |
| companyA | tam@example.com | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/opeZvaZx)